# SQL join in SUM function issue

Tags: sql, join, sum

I want to SUM t.amount, w.bStake and w.lStake (conditionally)

from transactions t and wagers w.

The amount should always be summed up and between back and profit should be a condition.

```
If w.Profit is positiv -> t.Amount + w.Back

If w.Profit is negativ -> t.Amount + w.Profit
```

My code that I use until this point looks like this:

```
SELECT 
  b.Bookie, 
  (SELECT SUM(t.Amount) FROM Transactions t WHERE t.Bookie = b.id)
FROM Bookie b
```

My tables are:

```
Bookie:
------------
Id : int (Primary Key)
Bookie : varchar


Transactions:
-------------------
Id : int (Primary Key)
Date : date
Bookie : int (Foreign Key)
Amount : decimal 


Wagers:
Id : int (Primary Key)
Profit : decimal
Back : decimal
Bookie : int (Foreign Key)
```

How can I solve this Issue? Or is it only possible if I restructure my database?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: JOIN appropriately then `sum(t.Amount + case when w.Profit >=0 then w.Back else w.Profit end)`

Comment: which server? myQql? MsSql?

Comment: @spiderman sorry I use MsSql

Comment: @AlexK. my code looks now like this http://pastebin.com/sVwc3GK0

But I get an error using this code. "Multiple columns are specified in an aggregated expression containing an outer reference. If an expression being aggregated contains an outer reference, then that outer reference must be the only column referenced in the expression."

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

you need to join the three tables, and then you can use case to get the sum:

```
SELECT 
  b.Bookie,
  SUM(CASE mySum WHEN If w.Profit >= 0 then t.Amount + w.Back
             ELSE t.Amount + w.Profit)
FROM Transactions as t inner join Bookie as b on t.Bookie = b.id
INNER JOIN Wagers as w on b.id = w.bookie
```

Comment: I get two Syntax error if I use your code

- in near of if-keyword
- in near of then-keyword

I used the Code in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2014

What is mySum after CASE keyword? Do I have to change mySum?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/FgWBgRUa This is the current code, but i get an error: Column 'Bookie.Bookie' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause. And if I use the Group by Clause, it would be calculated incorrectly.